# Javascript menu hover issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu

I'm trying to edit a javascript menu for a client that was created by their previous web developer. I'm not that great at Javascript. The client has asked that I make the menu expandables expand on ROLLOVER instead of on click. So, I changed .click to .hover and that worked great. The problem is, when you move your mouse off the main heading into the actual expandable region of the menu, the menu then fades/disappears away. I have a feeling this has to do with the .mouseneter section but I'm not sure how to proceed. Ideas?

```
function fadeMenu(el) {
    var delayMenu = setTimeout(function () {
        $(el).fadeOut(300);
        $(el).prev('.dropdown-toggle').removeClass('dropdown-enabled').animate({
            backgroundColor: 'transparent',
            color: '#000000'
        }, 300, function () {
            $(this).css({
                color: '',
                backgroundColor: ''
            });
        });
    }, 500);

    el.data('delayMenu', delayMenu);
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a.dropdown-toggle').click(function () {
        var menu = $(this).next('.dropdown-menu');
        var link = $(this).parent('li');
        var otherMenus = $('.dropdown-menu').not(menu);
        var otherToggles = $('.dropdown-toggle').not($(this));
        var toggle = $(this);
        var toColor = '';

        if ($(menu).is(":visible")) {
            if ($(link).is(":hover")) {
                toColor = '#ff7e00';
            } else {
                toColor = '#000000';
            }

            $(menu).fadeOut(300);
            $(toggle).removeClass('dropdown-    enabled').stop().animate({
                backgroundColor: 'transparent',
                color: toColor
            }, 300, function () {
                $(this).css({
                    color: '',
                    backgroundColor: ''
                });
            });
        } else {
            if ($(otherMenus).is(':visible')) {
                $(otherMenus).fadeOut(300);
            }

            $(toggle).stop().animate({
                backgroundColor: '#1f1f1f',
                color: '#ffffff'
            }, 300).addClass('dropdown-enabled');
            $(menu).fadeIn(300);

            $(otherToggles).stop().animate({
                backgroundColor: 'transparent',
                color: '#000000'
            }, 300, function () {
                $(otherToggles).css({
                    color: '',
                    backgroundColor: ''
                });
            });

        }

        return false;
    });

    $('.dropdown-menu').mouseenter(function () {
        clearTimeout($(this).data('delayMenu'));
    }).mouseleave(function () {
        fadeMenu($(this));
    });

    $('.dropdown-toggle').mouseenter(function () {
        clearTimeout($(this).next('.dropdown-menu').data('delayMenu'));
    }).mouseleave(function () {
        fadeMenu($(this).next('.dropdown-menu'));
    });
});
```

Comment: The issue isn't in the `.mouseenter()` but rather in the `.mouseleave()` - you need to adjust this to account for the possibility that when the mouse leaves, it is entering into a child element. I don't have any suggestions as to how to make that adjustment without seeing the html of the menu.

Comment: I was able to get it to do what i want by changing  "if ($(link).is(":hover")) {" to " if ($(link).is(":click")) {" and it works great, but now the dropdown menu stays there once the user takes their mouse off of the menu, it should disappear. Any suggestions @JeffreyBlake ? Can I Email you the link? (I just dont want to post it here)

Comment: This post is pretty old - is there any chance you @Dubs can post your solution?